# How to make a File Sharing website

Tags: java, javascript, php, html, css

What computer languages would I need to create a file sharing website? I think I would use HTML, CSS, Javascript, and PHP? Also how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would most likely need to use a server-based language, like SQL. HTML, CSS and PHP will be required, and Javascript a great plus.

Mainly, what you would do is use move_uploaded_file and is_uploaded_file after a form POST. See [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-uploaded-file.php) for more informations. You'd store the file name in your server, its location, its uploader, etc.

You'll need an authentification system, which the most primitive of will make use of [session variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), and the most advanced your SQL server, a hash function and the likes.
Good luck!

Comment: Since when MySQL become a *language*?

Comment: .. You're right. Sorry for the awful mixup.